# Windows 7 back up onto external hard drive that already has other data folders and files

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

When I tell windows 7 to create a system image and write it to an external hard drive that already has data saved on it that I don't want to lose, what happens when the system image is written to the external drive?

There is lots of room on the one TB external drive--836 GB are free out of 931 GB total volume.

My concern is that the backup program will reformat the entire external drive and I will lose all the existing data.  Will that happen, or will the backup program simply create a new folder next to all the other folders, preserving all the pre-existing data?

Comment: Windows will always create a folder called "WindowsImageBackup" on the root folder of your drive, e.g `T:\WindowsImageBackup`. Your other data is save

Answer (score 0):

I think your concern is that it will create a literal clone of your system and put that on a drive, which is not the case.  An image file is similar to any other file type, it will merely create a new file path as nixda indicates above.

The below is quoted from a forum thread about Acronis (a popular imaging program), and explains the technical details better than I can.

> True Image works by taking the raw bits on the platters and working with them - it doesn't care about filesystems, that has nothing to do with it as most people don't understand. It doesn't care if it's an NTFS filesystem, FAT32, FAT, HFS+, Ext3, etc. It's not relevant because all it does is see a partition that starts at  bit and ends at  bit and then it goes to work on the content from  to . It looks at the sectors on the drive which are 512 bytes long - again, the filesystem doesn't matter in this equation - and then works with the data it finds.
>
> It doesn't image empty space, it just puts placeholders to say "Ok, it's empty from sector  to sector  so nothing there." If you've got a 320GB hard drive, one partition, with 60GB of data on it, it's already noted the gap from 60GB to 320GB (the end of the drive) and then focuses on 60GB.